# DbExtensions - WHERE with AND and OR

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, dbextensions

I would like to build an SQL statement using DbExtensions.  I need to build a WHERE clause with AND and OR.  Something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE (Field1 LIKE '%a%' OR Field1 LIKE '%b%')
    AND (Field2 LIKE '%a%' OR Field2 LIKE '%b%')
```

I need to do this from within a loop.

```
var builder = SQL
    .SELECT("*")
    .FROM("myTable")
    .WHERE();

foreach (var field in fields) {
    foreach (var value in field.values) {
        builder.AppendClause("WHERE", " OR ", field.columnName + " LIKE {0}", new object[] { "%" + value.Value + "%" });
    }
}
```

The above code seems to produce an SQL statement like so

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE Field1 LIKE '%a%' OR Field1 LIKE '%b%'
    OR Field2 LIKE '%a%' OR Field2 LIKE '%b%'
```

As you can see, if doesnt have any brackets and there is an OR instead of an AND.

It there anyway i can get DbExtensions to do what i want using the methods available, without having to write this all to another stringBuilder?

**EDIT**
I have changed my code as suggested to this

```
var builder = SQL
   .SELECT("*")
   .FROM("myTable")
   .WHERE();

foreach (var field in fields) {
   builder._OR(field.values, field.columnName + " LIKE {0}", v => new object[1] { "%" + v.ToString() +  "%" });
}
```

But i also need to append an OR into the current block.  So lets say that each field has a property called "CheckBlank" and if true, i need to add " OR FieldX IS NULL" how can this be done?  So i would expect to end up with SQL like this if Field1.CheckBlank was true, but Field2 CheckBlank is false

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE (Field1 LIKE '%a%' OR Field1 LIKE '%b%' OR Field1 IS NULL)
    AND (Field2 LIKE '%a%' OR Field2 LIKE '%b%')
```

Comment: can you provide link of DbExtension library?

Comment: https://github.com/maxtoroq/DbExtensions

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sample to generate specified query.

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE (Field1 LIKE '%a%' OR Field1 LIKE '%b%')
    AND (Field2 LIKE '%a%' OR Field2 LIKE '%b%')
```

Code snippet to do this:

```
var builder = SQL
    .SELECT("*")
    .FROM("myTable")
    .WHERE();

foreach (var field in fields) {
        builder.WHERE("").Append("(")
        var index = 0;
        foreach (var value in field.values) {
            builder.AppendClause("WHERE", index == 0 ? "": " OR ", field.columnName + " LIKE {0}", new object[] { "%" + value.Value + "%" });
        }
        index++;
        builder.Append(")");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var builder = SQL
   .SELECT("*")
   .FROM("myTable")
   .WHERE();

foreach (var field in fields) {
   builder._OR(field.values, field.columnName + " LIKE {0}", v => new object[1] { "%" + v.ToString() +  "%" });
}
```

I don't know if merging the `%` with the parameter value is the best option. I mostly work with MySQL, where I do `Field1 LIKE CONCAT('%', {0}, '%')`. Don't append parameter values to the format string, it could expose an injection.

Comment: Max how could i append a query to an OR?  Edited question with more detail. Great library btw!